# How to switch audio devices in Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm developing on android.I'm trying to switch audio play devices in app.I try the code below:

> audioManager.setParameters("audio_devices_out_active=AUDIO_HDMI");

which doesn't work.How can I change the audio output between HDMI、bluetooth、speaker、headset or other kind of devices on android TV platform?